# Very large list with sublists of varying dimension

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very large list of events,Evin, grouped into sublists. All these sublists have 15 elements each and the large list has about 1 - 2 million of these sublists. I now want to regroup that large list of lists by introducing another layer of lists such that some of the original sublists are grouped together into events; the grouping is done according to two elements of the original sublists.

The problem is that that these new event sublists have varying dimension, i.e. number of elements, varying between roughly 4 and 25. So far, I have done that by defining a new 3-layered list

```
Ev  = Table[0., {nf}, {np}, {15}]
```

and then filling in the events of Ev from the original list Evin. Here *nf* is the original very large number, say 1 Million, and *np* is taken to the maximum possible dimension of the new sublist *np* = 25. This obviously creates huge lists andd wastes a lot of storage since most of the new event sublists have much less elements than 25. How can avoid that, i.e. how can I work with varying dimension np?

Comment: Is your data numeric only? You could use `SparseArray`s.